# Mirror and Subdivision Surface is causing a problem

Tags: mirror, subdivision-surface

I added Mirror modifier to my Archway and everything is fine untill I add Subdivision Surface.

[image]

[image]

Without Subdivision Surface modifier:

[image]

What Am I doing wrong?

Here's Blender file:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an inner face, delete it. Also, enable the *Clipping* option of the *Mirror* modifier.

[image]